# jQuery: delay the function issue with each

Tags: jquery

delay function not working with each.

what i am doing is when user click on close button first fadeout the popup and then remove style attribute from all li.

issue is fadeout is before the popup fadeout the style attribute is action firing , that is why i used delay to slowdown removeAttr event. but getting some issue with the code..

in one of the article i read to use index with each i tried that one but still not getting issue with.

```
   jQuery('.clsbb').click(function(){
   jQuery('.new-rows').fadeOut(3000);
   jQuery('.products li').each(function(index){

    jQuery(this).delay(1000 * index).removeAttr('style');
     });
       });

   <div class="clsbb">close</div>
   <ul>
      <li style="margin-top:10px;">row2</li>
       <li style="margin-top:10px;">row2</li>
        <li style="margin-top:10px;">row2</li>
         <li style="margin-top:10px;">row2</li>
           <li class="new-rows">popup</li>
   </ul>
```

need help to fadeout popup first then removeAttr

http://jsfiddle.net/xm5LE/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`complete` argument in `fadeout`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) :

```
jQuery('.new-rows').fadeOut(3000, function(){
    // this code will be called after the animation completes
    jQuery('.products li').removeAttr('style');
});
```

---

[edit] complete solution :

```
<div class="clsbb">close</div>
<ul class="products">
    <li style="margin-top:10px;">row2</li>
    <li style="margin-top:10px;">row2</li>
    <li style="margin-top:10px;">row2</li>
    <li style="margin-top:10px;">row2</li>
    <li class="new-rows">popup</li>
</ul>

jQuery('.clsbb').click(function () {
    jQuery('.new-rows').fadeOut(3000, function () {
       jQuery('.new-rows').remove();
       jQuery('.products li').removeAttr('style');
    });
});
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/xm5LE/4/)

Comment: how can i use each in fadeout function?

Comment: @JackTorris: check your markup, nobody has the `products` class. Corrected : http://jsfiddle.net/xm5LE/1/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42321/discussion-between-jack-torris-and-legec)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using callback methods:

```
jQuery('.new-rows').fadeOut(3000, function(){
  // Use callback method.
  jQuery('.products li').removeAttr('style');  // Not sure why you have used 1000 * index. Use it here as well if required.
});
```

**Edit** as per Jack Torris
`jQuery('.products li').removeAttr('style');` this will remove style from all li not just one. But if you still want to use .each

```
jQuery('.new-rows').fadeOut(3000, function(){
  // Use callback method.
  jQuery('.products li').each ( function(){  $(this).removeAttr('style'); } );
});
```

Comment: jQuery('.products li').removeAttr('style');  it will remove the attribute from one li only.. is it possible to use each i n fadeout funvtion?

Comment: @JackTorris `jQuery('.products li').removeAttr('style');`  this will remove style from all **li** not just one. But if you still want to use .each see my edited answer.